# Lubuntu 14.10 High CPU usage and choppy video playing

Tags: lubuntu, video, cpu, 14.10

I have an Asus Notebook (2007) with 1 gb ram and 900 Mhz Mobile Intel® 915GM/GMS, 910GML Express Graphics. I use Lubuntu 14.10 with about 300 mb memory usage,but the problem is high CPU usage(100 %) especially when I am playing videos. Also video playing is choppy and laggy especially when I am on facebook and I want to see a video. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you are having an awful PC, the cpu worse than the only 1 GB of RAM.
What you installed?

Two must-have for a slow and outdated computer: preload and zram.

So, open terminal and type **sudo apt-get install preload zram-config -y**
Then reboot and tell me if your computer is in "better shape" ;)